# $.getJSON not logging any results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make an api call using $.getJSON but I either don't get any results, or my code isn't well structured. Here's my current code:

```
function callAPI(){

var api = "https://callmyapi/random/evenmorerandom";
$.getJSON(
    api,
    {
        playerId : "myID",
        action : "call"
    },
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This code is called in a simple html page that is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- GET JQUERY -->
<script src="http://j.mp/jqymin"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="callAPI.js">
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Currently the console.log instruction is not logging anything. Is there anything wrong with my code, or I'm just not receiving anything from the API call?

Comment: Actually it seems you aren't calling the function initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you are calling your `callAPI function` and add `.fail()` so you know if it failed.

```
   function callAPI(){

    var api = "https://callmyapi/random/evenmorerandom";
    $.getJSON(
        api,
        {
            playerId : "myID",
            action : "call"
        },
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(){ //<-- fail function
          console.log('Get JSON failed');
        });
    } //End of function callAPI
    callAPI(); //<-- add this to call your function
```

Answer (score 1):

You wan't to make the api call when the page is loaded?

Add something like below to your `callAPI.js`:

```
$(function() {
  callAPI();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

on page load this will init the function; try this;

```
   <script language="JavaScript" src="callAPI.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
         callAPI();
    });
    </script>
```